# About geodesic vector fields and the status of a classic problem on the number of closed geodesics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, open-problems, geodesics, closed-geodesic

A classical problem in differential geometry is to determine whether every compact Riemannian manifold admits infinitely many geometrically distinct closed geodesics. A good reference on the subject is [this survey article](https://aimath.org/pastworkshops/geodesicsproblems.pdf) by Burns and Matveev. Since this article is almost ten years old, I am wondering if there has been any significant updates to the status of this problem. In particular, I found [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.04017v6) which claims to have a full solution in the affirmative, although I cannot find evidence of it being published anywhere since it was posted on the arxiv a number of years ago.

Regardless, my main question is about geodesic vectors fields and their relation to this problem, which are (nowhere vanishing) vector fields on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ such that their orbits are all geodesics. [This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/249159/143629) by MO user Thomas Rot claims that a result of Lyusternik and Fet gives that every geodesic vector field on a closed Riemannian manifold must carry a closed orbit. But the only such theorem I can find is [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyusternik%E2%80%93Fet_theorem), with the linked reference at the end of the wiki being in Russian. This is seemingly weaker than what's claimed in Thomas' answer, since a geodesic vector field contains only a few of the many more geodesics on $M$. In fact, if *every* geodesic vector field contains a closed geodesic, it would seem that the main problem should have a much easier approach: simply find infinitely many geodesic vector fields with distinct orbits (if this isn't in fact much harder than I imagine).

So in short, do Lyusternik and Fet really have another result just like in Thomas' answer? Does it at least hold on the $3$-sphere?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414063/closed-geodesics-on-closed-manifolds

Comment: @MoisheKohan ah I hadn't seen your post! Seems like most of the same references are there too. Seems like the only new part of my post is the Lyusternik and Fet results, then.

Comment: BTW, The claim that every geodesic vector field on a closed manifold carries a closed orbit is clearly false (just look at a flat torus).